# add_rewrite_rule with optional parameters

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, regex

Using add_rewrite_rule() to handle things like this for the custom post type "catalogs", page name "cars":

/catalogs/cars/
/catalogs/cars/p1/
/catalogs/cars/p1/p2/
/catalogs/cars/p1/p2/p3/

I never have more than 3 parameters after /cars/, but all of them with optional query string parameters. Like this:

/catalogs/cars/p1/p2/?weight-max=3200

Here's my code:

```
add_rewrite_rule( 
    '^catalogs/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?', 
    'index.php?catalogs=$matches[1]&p1=$matches[2]&p2=$matches[3]&p3=$matches[4]', 
    'top'
);
```

Works great for when there's 3 parameters (like /catalogs/cars/p1/p2/p3/), but it doesn't work for when there's 0-2 parameters.

Have tried making parts of the regex optional, but I guess my regex skills aren't that fantastic...

Have a trick for making the number of parameters dynamic, so everything from 0-3 parameters can be handled?

Thanks :thumbsup:

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, just had to remember all the ? marks.

It works when the regex is like this:

```
'index.php?catalogs=$matches[1]&p1=$matches[2]&p2=$matches[3]&p3=$matches[4]'
```

Comment: That's exactly the same as the second argument in the question isn't it?